# How to pivot in DBT without aggregating the value

Tags: jinja2, dbt

Using DBT, how does one pivot a table without aggregating? When looking at the [pivot macro](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/pivot.sql) it mentions the aggregation function, which defaults to sum.

To visualize the problem:

| Color | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| blue | 2023-01-01 | 2 |
| red | 2023-01-02 | 3 |
| blue | 2023-01-02 | 7 |

Into

| Date | red | blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-01-02 | 3 | 7 |

So instead of aggregating, it would move the value

Answer (score 2):

In your use case, even if you perform some aggregation, the values would remain the same since you only have one occurrence per day and color.

So, I believe the syntax would look like this:

```sql
select
  date,
  {{ dbt_utils.pivot(
      'color',
      dbt_utils.get_column_values(ref('your_model_name'), 'color'),
      then_value='amount'
  ) }}
from {{ ref('your_model_name') }}
group by 1
```